# Error when trying to access loader data in react router ERROR: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React-Router and trying to get my loader data using the `useParams()` hook, but I get the following error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
import { useLoaderData, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export async function githubInfoLoader() {
  const { username } = useParams(); //The error shows in this line of code
  let url = `https://api.github.com/users/kunal22-gupta`
  if (username) url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json();
}

export default function Github() {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center text-2xl py-5">
        Github followers: {data.followers}
      </h1>
      <div className="flex justify-center mb-10">
        <img
          src={data.avatar_url}
          alt="pfp"
          width={300}
          className="rounded-full"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I was trying to get the loader value and fetch github profile data, but I got an error saying hooks can only be used inside of function component.

Comment: The issue is **exactly** what the error says. You can only use hooks inside functional components or inside custom hooks. Here you're trying to use it inside a regular function. Not allowed

Comment: as mentioned above:
You need to make it into a custom hook if you want to use that `githubInfoLoader` function w/ useParams:

you can just name it `useGithubInfoLoader` and it will know that it should be a react custom hook.
Since you're doing a fetch, you should will need to send the useParams `username` into another fetch function that takes in a username argument. gl

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useLoaderData, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export async function GithubInfoLoader() { // component name must be starting from capital letter 
     const {username} = useParams(); 
     let url = `https://api.github.com/users/kunal22-gupta`
     if(username) url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`
     const response = await fetch(url);
     return response.json();
}

export default function Github() {
     const data = useLoaderData();
     return (
          <div>
               <h1 className="text-center text-2xl py-5">Github followers: 
                 {data.followers} 
               </h1>
              <div className="flex justify-center mb-10">
               <img 
                 src={data.avatar_url} 
                 alt="pfp" 
                 width={300} 
                 className="rounded-full"
               />
             </div>
          </div>
     );
}
```

In React Js, component names must start with a capital letter. try this now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

React hooks can only be called from React functions and custom React hooks. The `Route` component's `loader` function is neither. Fortunately for you the loader functions are passed the [routes path parameters in args](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader#params).

Note also that loader functions also understand how to return `fetch` responses. In other words, you can simply return `fetch` and the data router understand to also unpack the JSON response and return *that* to the routed component.

```js
export function githubInfoLoader({ params }) {
  const { username = "kunal22-gupta" } = params;

  return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);
}
```

For more details, see the [loader](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want to use ANY hook (not just the one in question, which has a solution in the library itself) You can work around it by initializing the hook in your `Routes` component and use curried function syntax to pass the hook along:

```
// App.tsx

export default function App() {
  const { login } = useAuth(); // Sample hook which is needed in our loader function

  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" loader={DashboardLoader(login)}>
      /*                                      ^^^^^
                            Pass in our required function to loader
      */
      </Route>
    )
  );

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

Then in your loader function:

```
// Dashboard.tsx

export const loader =
  (login: AuthContextType["login"]) =>
  async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
    const response = await fakeLoginAPI();

    login(response); // Now we have access to our hook. Beautiful!

    return redirect("/dashboard/members");
  };
```

You can read more about this idea in this article:
[How to use custom hooks in React router’s data router action and loader](https://medium.com/@mohsentaleb/how-to-use-custom-hooks-in-react-router-v6-4-data-router-action-and-loader-3f4669608dc6)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue with `useLoaderData()` hook.
The problem itself is clearly stated in the error message.

I was actually using a class component.

```
class SampleComp extends Component{
 render() {
        const { myData } = useLoaderData();
        return (
            <div>{myData}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

But the [documentation](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both) mentions that You can’t use Hooks ***inside*** a class component.

So just converted it into a *Function Component*.

```
Function SampleComp () {
   const { myData } = useLoaderData();
   return (
     <div>{myData}</div>
   );
}
```

The error was gone.